# Are the errors returned by an API considered part of the interface?

Tags: api-design

Many tend to focus on the method signature when discussing a programming interface, and error handling becomes an afterthought.

In your software development practice, are the error responses considered part of the interface? Is this an industry-accepted practice?

I recently came across a requirement that states that a new API should "keep the same interface" as the API we are replacing.

I'm split as to whether to interpret this literally where some abstractions leaked by the old API errors may remain leaked in the new API or take a more relaxed stance where the method signatures remain intact, and error handling is better encapsulated to stop exposing unnecessary details to the users of the new API.

Comment: Errors must be documented and in a known format that does not change for that version of the API.   Changing the error responses could break any existing code that parses those responses.  Consider the fun if Microsoft suddenly changed the errors returned by the Win32 API -- I'd expect a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of apps suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.  That is, only make those kinds of changes for a new version of the API that the caller knows is a new version, not a replacement for the existing code and version 1 API.